# Stack allocations with a negative offset in a recursive function of more than 4 parameters

Tags: assembly, recursion, stack, mips, offset

Okay, so we have a function that takes 5 arguments passed from main.

$a0-$a3 and $t0

```
# Prologue: set up stack and frame poiters for search 
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -28           # allocate stack space -- 28 needed here
    sw      $fp, 0($sp)             # save caller's frame pointer 
    sw      $ra, 4($sp)             # save return address
    addi    $fp, $sp, 24            # setup the search frame pointer

# Preserve $a register arguments
    sw      $a0, 0($sp)     # addr of element in array
    sw      $a1, 4($sp)     # searchValue
    sw      $a2, 8($sp)     # indexLeft
    sw      $a3, 12($sp)    # indexRight

    # Get the 5th argument
    lw      $s5, 44($sp)    # level = 28 + 16
```

I get how this works. However, main doesn't store $t0 in 16($sp). Instead is stores $t0 in -4($sp).

What does that mean? what do I set my offset to in order to load the value stored from $t0 onto the stack into my $s5 register? I'm leaning towards 24($sp) (28 + (-4)) but I'm not sure.

This is for a recursive function, so I want to make sure each register loads the proper values every time the function calls itself and allocates another 28 bytes from my stack pointer.

And as far as the actual recursive call, I don't understand how to use $v0? If someone could explain how it is used, I would appreciate it